# How can I handle SIGCHLD?

Tags: c, sigchld

I need to handle `SIGCHLD` properly. How can I use it with my existing code? at the moment I cant wait for the child process unless I use `0` instead of `WNOHANG|WUNTRACED`.

```
status = 0; 
pid_t child, endID;

if(amp == 1)
        signal( SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN ); 

child = fork(); 

if (child  <  0) {    
        perror("fork() error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

} else if (child == 0) { 
        // do sth here
        perror("error\n");

} else { 
        //sleep(1)
```

If I remove `sleep` then parent is executed 1st.. why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Allow mixing of background and foreground processes by writing and installing a proper signal handler function

Comment: What should the signal handler do ?

Comment: kills or ignores zombies

Comment: As written, you will likely have `waitpid()` return immediately because (a) the child has not died and (b) you said 'do not wait for the child to die'.  You would normally wrap the `waitpid()` in a loop.  Also, it is not clear why you're waiting for `vars->pid` when the child pid is only available in `child`.  It seems a little odd that you pass `vars->status` rather than `&vars->status` or `&status`.  The variables `status` and `endID` are unused.

Comment: This seems to be related to [Example of `waitpid()`, `WNOHANG`, and `SIGCHLD`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155810/example-of-waitpid-wnohang-and-sigchld).

Answer (score 35):

Here is a start (but read below):

```
static void
child_handler(int sig)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    /* EEEEXTEERMINAAATE! */
    while((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
        ;
}

/* Establish handler. */
struct sigaction sa;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sa.sa_handler = child_handler;

sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);
```

---

Of course, this is all **pointless**. If the parent simply ignores `SIGCHLD`, the children are silently reaped and won't turn into zombies.

Quoting [TLPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Linux_Programming_Interface):

> Explicitly setting the disposition of SIGCHLD to SIG_IGN causes any
>   child process that subsequently terminates to be immediately removed
>   from the system **instead of being converted into a zombie**.

So something like this should do the trick for you:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); /* Silently (and portably) reap children. */
```

Comment: where should i call this method?

Comment: @kanoz Read the last paragraph :-)

Comment: Just came across this question because i needed to handle SIGCHLD, and  i didn't find it very clear on where the line you gave us should be called. As it doesn't need any pid or anything i just put it anywhere, is it right? Thanks @cnicutar.

Comment: @polar Somewhere before starting to fork.

Comment: As you said: Explicitly setting the disposition of SIGCHLD to SIG_IGN causes any child process that subsequently terminates to be immediately removed from the system instead of being converted into a zombie. How can check & prevent this situation? I think this thing is happening in my case?

Comment: @kapilddit I don't understand the question completely. Do you want to prevent the children from being reaped automatically ? Do you want to know if you process sets the disposition to SIG_IGN ?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. I want my process to be converted to zombie. So I can read the status of child. currently I am getting -1 from waitpid with errno ECHILD. I want to know my process sets the disposition to SIG_IGN ?

Comment: If using Linux you can look in `/proc/[pid]/status` and see the mask `SigIgn`.

Comment: I am not able to see any pid for child process in /proc/pid/status. Do I need to write signal handler? I don't want to kill or ignore zombie child process. I want child pid as return value from waitpid.

Comment: The explicit child_handler approach is not entirely pointless.  It has the virtue of making it so that SIGCHLD interrupts system calls such as read.  That can prevent a parent process from blocking forever on read.