# How to forking process in a way such that reaping the child isn't neccessary

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, fork

I seem to have a vague memory that some facility in Linux exists that allows one to fork() a process in such a way that the child is automatically reaped by the system without a zombie being created. What is this mechanism? Or is my memory just wrong?

Comment: From the [wait man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait): A child that terminates, but has not been waited for becomes a "zombie"......If a parent process terminates, then its "zombie" children (if any) are adopted by init(8), which automatically performs a wait to remove the zombies. "

Comment: You could daemonize the child so it immediately loses its parent.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks. I know about zombies. I thought there was a way to fork() and not need to reap because you don't care about the child's return code and have the system auto reap the child so that a zombie isn't created.

Comment: Wasn't clear from your question. But yes, @KerrekSB describes that.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you. I thought there was a much simpler way. Perhaps my memory is wrong. I wonder if I'm thinking of some Glib function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015830

Comment: @Chimera: Daemonizing is pretty damn simple. Don't know how much simpler you need it to be.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes it's simple. I just thought I remembered a simpler way. As it turns out I was thinking of Glib's g_spawn_* methods.

Comment: @Chimera: The benefit of that seems mainly that it hooks up the I/O with the new process for you, which can indeed be quite fiddly and tricky (and deadlock-prone). (But you don't usually do I/O with daemon processes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The portable way to do this is to double-fork:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid>0) {
    int status;
    while (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) && !WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status) || WEXITSTATUS(status)) goto error;
} else if (!pid) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid) _exit(pid<0);
    else {
        // do child work here
        _exit(0);
    }
} else goto error;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking of Glib's [g_spawn_*](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) methods that auto-reap the child unless you specify you don't want that default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore SIGCHLD so it's doesn't create zombie ;)

`signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);`

doc here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html

Comment: Thank you. Saw that as well. But I read that it's not supported in older Linux kernels? And of course I'm working on embedded Linux systems with very old kernels.

Comment: @Chimera That is correct: it's not supported prior to `POSIX.1-2001`, which is aligned with the C99 (`ISO/IEC 9899:1999`). If you're using an older system, this will not work.

Comment: @DevNull You **really** down vote this! It's not a wrong answer Omg http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157841/what-do-i-do-when-someone-deliberately-downvotes-many-of-my-answers. He never say in his question that he work with old kernels!

Comment: This isn't serial downvoting. I was curious why you so vehemently defended your critique of my answer the other day, despite being proven dead wrong, so I investigated other answers of yours because I was curious if you were spreading misinformation on SO: I was correct. Also, TC noted in a comment **just above this one** that he/she is using older kernels.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done via [prctl()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html)

`prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM);`

The above line inserted in the child process can cause it's termination when the parent process is dead. This can also work when any sub-reapers die(after they parent the child process), and if you need it's actual parent's death to kill the child process, then store the parent's `pid` before `fork()` and check it in the child process.

`if (getppid() != parent_pid_before_fork)
        exit(1);`