# Monitoring and restarting child process when fails/exits

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, waitpid

I've created a rudimentary example of monitoring a child process and restarting it when it fails or exits. What is the preferred/more robust method of doing this? Is it good practice to continuously poll for a change in status? My understanding is that I should utilize something like `SIGCHLD`but have been unable to find any good examples.

I'm an embedded C coder mainly and this is my first attempt at trying to understand `fork()`.The purpose of this code will eventually be to monitor a call to another program using `exec()` and restart this program if and when it fails or finishes.

**Edit:**
After comments from @cnicutar I have rewritten the example below in a way I think makes more sense in the hope that it is of use to somebody later. I would like the parent to monitor a child process whilst foing other things and make a new call to `exec` on a new `fork` when the child process fails/finishes. I want to try and use unix signals to achieve this

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t cpid;
    int status;
    cpid = fork();
    for (;;)
    {
        switch (cpid)
        {
        case -1 : //Fork failure
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;

        case 0 : //Child Process
            exec(some function);
            return 0; //exit child process
            break;

        default : //Parent process
            if (waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG) != 1) cpid = fork(); //restart 
            //Do parent stuff here...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `SIGCHLD` handler won't buy you much since you already wait all the time and only do that - there's nothing else to "interrupt".

One thing I would suggest is a threshold such that the process doesn't die/start too often.

> My understanding is that I should utilize something like SIGCHLD but
>   have been unable to find any good examples

You use `SIGCHLD` to know when to wait. A typical `SIGCHLD` handler just does `waitpid` in a loop until no children are left. In your case you don't need that since your main code is a loop stopped on `waitpid`.

---

EDIT

You can find plenty of examples for `SIGCHLD` handling. One such example is [How can I handle sigchld in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7171836/714501). In that code, after the `while` you can just `fork`:

```
while((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
        ;

pid = fork();
switch (pid)
...
```

To reiterate, if you do this `SIGCHLD` will be called every time a child dies and after you properly wait for it you can just `fork` another. This only makes sense if the parent has better stuff to do in the meantime than to just block on `waitpid`.

---

Word to the wise. There are certain functions that must not be called from a signal handler lest you add difficult bugs to your program. Look up "async signal safe" functions: these and only these can be called from a signal handler. Some of the most common functions (like `printf` and `malloc`) cannot be called from a signal handler.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I realize now my question was not so much how to monitor/wait for the child process to end but what the best practices are for restarting it. My method seems of setting a flag seems to work but is there a native C, unix way to handle this?
 `if (alive == 0) cpid = fork(); alive = 1;`

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz I am not sure you really need the flag. The only way for the fork to be reached is for `waitpid` to unblock, which happens when the process dies or is killed by a signal.

Comment: Of course, sorry. What I meant was suppose the parent process was not waiting and only checking the child process with an if once per the main loop. How would this be handled without calling `fork` each time?

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz If I understand your question correctly, then yes, it is indeed possible to install a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` and `fork` from it. `fork` happens to be async-signal-safe so this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @cnicutar, I've rewritten the code example and restated my question in a (hopefully) cleaner and more concise way.

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz I am not sure about the way you modified the code. I think you can either keep the old version, just without `alive` or add a new version with only a `SIGCHLD` handler that forks. If you want me to I can write a skeleton for such a handler.

Comment: Its the SIGCHLD handler I don't know understand how to write or where its called. I hoped modifying the code made it easier to explain my issue. Thanks for the continuing help!

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz I added a link to an example and a few lines of advice.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for but lacked the knowledge to know how to ask!