# How to wait for a child process and get its return value

Tags: c, linux, fork, waitpid

I am trying to fork my C application, running on an embedded linux environment, and get its return value for failure/success analysis.

I looked at similar questions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075307/what-does-signalsigchld-sig-dfl-mean), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064988/dont-want-to-remove-terminated-child-process-immediately-need-to-become-zombie%20%22this2), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590228/check-shell-command-return-value-in-c), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676893/return-value-of-execl) and some other Q/A..) but still can't get it to work.

code:

```
static int fork_test(const char *src, const char *dst)
{
int childExitStatus;
pid_t pid;
int status;

DEBUG_PRINT("forking");

pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) { // child
    sleep(2);
    DEBUG_PRINT("child - exiting");
    exit(1);
}
else if (pid < 0) {
    return -1;
}
else { // parent
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        pid_t ws = waitpid(pid, &childExitStatus, WNOHANG);
        if (-1 == ws)
        {
            DEBUG_PRINT("parent - failed wait. errno = %d", errno);
            return -1;
        }
        if (0 == ws)
        {
            DEBUG_PRINT("parent - child is still running");
            sleep(1);
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (10 == i)
        return -1;

    DEBUG_PRINT("parent - done waiting");

    if (WIFEXITED(childExitStatus)) /* exit code in childExitStatus */
    {
        DEBUG_PRINT("parent - got status %d", childExitStatus);
        status = WEXITSTATUS(childExitStatus); /* zero is normal exit */
        if (0 != status)
        {
            DEBUG_PRINT("parent - picked up bad exit status");
            return status;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        DEBUG_PRINT("parent - bad exit route");
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

This provided this output:

> forking
>   parent - child is still running
>   parent - child is still running
>   parent - child is still running
>   child - exiting
>   parent - failed wait. errno = 10

note that errno=10 means ECHILD.

so i tried to add:

```
...
DEBUG_PRINT("forking");
signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_DFL);
pid = fork();
...
```

(or with SIG_IGN) with no difference.
I can successfully add a signal handler for SIGCHLD, and might be able to wait for signal, instead of the child process, with sigwait() or the likes, but it seems like a bad solution..

Any idea what I'm missing here?

> $ uname -mrso
>   Linux 3.18.20 armv7l GNU/Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code nicely tests for "errors". Good.

But the code unfortunately misses to catch the case you are after, the one where `waitpid()` actually returns the child's PID.

You could achieve this like so:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    pid_t ws = waitpid(pid, &childExitStatus, WNOHANG);
    if (-1 == ws)
    {
        DEBUG_PRINT("parent - failed wait. errno = %d", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    else if (0 == ws)
    {
        DEBUG_PRINT("parent - child is still running");
        sleep(1);
        continue;
    }

    DEBUG_PRINT("parent - successfully waited for child with PID %d", (int) ws);

    break;
}
```

Comment: correct. too much Q&A-ing made me look for issues too deep. thanks