# When to use waitpid() to find status of background process

Tags: c, fork, jobs, waitpid

I'm trying to write basic shell program that will manage job control with background processes.  I understand to send a process to the background you call `fork()`, but don't wait for it in the parent.  However, I also know you need to call `waitpid()` with the `WNOHANG` option to get the status of a process that has finished executing.  My question is when and how to call the `waitpid()` in my code in order to know when a child finishes.  Here's what I have so far for just executing a process in the background:

```
for (;;) {
    char buff[PATH_MAX + 1];                    
    char *cwd = getcwd(buff, PATH_MAX + 1);
    printf("%s/", cwd); 
    char *cmd = readline("shell>");  //This code just sets up a cmd prompt 
    if (strcmp(tokList[0], bgCmd) == 0) {
        //If the user inputs 'bg' then run the command in the background parent
        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid == 0) {
            execvp(bgTokList[0], bgTokList);  // This array contains just the arguments to be executed
            perror("execvp");
            return -1;
        } else {
            //parent
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When a child process has completed, the parent will receive the signal `SIGCHLD`. Your signal handler can then reap the status.

[Using an existing example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7171836/315052), you can modify it for your own needs.