# What is the use of ignoring `SIGCHLD` signal with `sigaction(2)`?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, c99

It turns out that we can prevent appearing of a zombie process (i.e. the one whose parent doesn't `wait()` for it to `_exit()`) by specifying `SIGCHLD` signal to be ignored with `sigaction()` by its parent. However, it seems like `SIGCHLD` is ignored by default anyway. How come does this work?

```
int main (void) {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN; //handle signal by ignoring
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, 0) == -1) {
        perror(0);
        exit(1);
    }
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { //child process
        _exit(0);
    }
    do_something(); //parent process
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default behavior of `SIGCHLD` is to discard the signal, but the child process is kept as a zombie until the parent calls `wait()` (or a variant) to get its termination status.

But if you explicitly call `sigaction()` with the disposition `SIG_IGN`, that causes it not to turn the child into a zombie -- when the child exits it is reaped immediately. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7171836/1491895

The POSIX way to get this behavior is by calling `sigaction` with `handler = SIG_DFL` and `flags` containing `SA_NOCLDWAIT`. This is in Linux since 2.6.

Comment: Does this mean that discarding signal and ignoring signal are two different behaviors?

Comment: What's special is ignoring it explicitly by calling `sigaction()`. It doesn't change how the signal is treated in your process, but it changes what happens to the process that exits.

Comment: @igor Yes, discarding a signal and ignoring it are different things. Discarding means the signal is basically just thrown away, while ignoring means it's actually considered delivered, but there is no handler or any other special action performed.

Comment: @twalberg But except in this special case, there's no behavioral difference between them.

Comment: @Barmar That may be true in this particular case, but it's not necessarily true across all the different signals. Thus, it can be important to understand the difference between throwing away a signal and delivering it but not doing anything in response...

Comment: @twalberg My claim is that this is the only case where there's a difference. Are there others I didn't think of?

Comment: Or are you saying that this is the only case now, but we can't predict the future?

Comment: @Barmar `kill -l` on my Linux system lists 64 different signals. Not having fully memorized the semantics of all of those, I can't say that for sure - hence the "not necessarily". There might be others where the difference is significant, but I can't state definitively one way or the other without more research.

Comment: @twalberg This is the only one I know of that has this special behavior. I'll stick by my assertion unless someone can provide a counterexample. In any case, it's not germane to the answer.

Comment: @Barmar If I don't care about my child process' exit status then instead of using `wait` can I simply use `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);` in order to prevent zombie processes?

Comment: The portable method is what I described in my last paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion is that you seem to be asuming that "`SIGCHLD` is ignored by default" means that the default disposition of the signal is `SIG_IGN`.

That's not the case. The default disposition is `SIG_DFL`. When you set it to `SIG_IGN` you're actually changing it. And after you've set it as `SIG_IGN`, you can revert it back to `SIG_DFL`, getting the original behavior again.