# How parent process wait all child processes terminate

Tags: c

I am new to C , So i  only know simple functions.(ex: wait(NULL) ).

Here is my main question :

> Modify the program so that only the parent process creates 3 child processes, and each
>   new created process calls a function CPU(). In addition, make the parent process wait for
>   each child’s termination.

**I know this one is the correct answer**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i ;

    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int ret = fork();
        if(ret == 0){
            printf("My process ID is %d\n", getpid());
            return 0;
        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) //Line B
        wait(NULL);
}
```

**but my problems are**

1. why below code is wrong when wait is executed by the parent in the loop

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
       int i ;

       for( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           int ret = fork();

           if(ret == 0) {
               printf("My process ID is %d\n", getpid());
               return 0;
           }
           else
               wait(NULL);
       }
   }
   ```
2. in very first code why do we write `wait(NULL)` inside a for loop?
   can't we write it without a for loop
3. **if** there is no "return 0" in child process, should the for loop be changed to

   ```
   for (i = 0; i <7; i++)
       wait(NULL);
   ```
4. I don't know how to write the `CPU` function

Comment: It is not a C question, since `wait` is not mentioned in the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). It could be a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) question, a Unix one, or a Linux one. So **edit your question** to improve it and give some [MCVE]. BTW, StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework site. Read [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or something newer related to Unix or Linux or POSIX programming. Read also [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: ... and read of course [wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)

Comment: At last, compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't think this is as straight "do my homework problem", but more like some questions whose answer does not become apparent until you've written a *meaningful* child process.

Comment: I gave several links to help the OP

Comment: @paulsm4 but it isn't, this question has 4 subitems, none of which is addressed in that question - **2 of the answers there even advices writing the incorrect code that OP asks about in #1!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This code would not execute the child processes *in parallel* but execute each one sequentially. The difference does not show *until* the child processes do something beyond printing one message and exiting (you could add `sleep(1)`).
2. `wait` function will wait for the termination of *one* child process (whichever finishes first). If you've got 3 child processes, you must call `wait` successfully at least that 3 times to ensure that each one of them has terminated. Perhaps easier would be to call `wait` until it sets `errno` to `ECHILD`, meaning that there are no children left:

   ```
   while (1) {
       errno = 0;
       if (wait(NULL) == -1) {
           if (errno != ECHILD) {
               perror("Unexpected error from wait");
           }
           break;
       }       
   }
   ```
3. Each parent process should wait for its **own children** ([or set the `SIGCHLD` disposition to `SIG_IGN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601337/what-is-the-use-of-ignoring-sigchld-signal-with-sigaction2)). Instead of counting the number of `wait`s, use the code above
4. This means just: "call a function by the name `CPU`", i.e.

   ```
   void CPU(void) {
   }
   ```

   in the child process.

---

BTW, your code is missing the necessary headers for a couple functions -

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

for `wait`,

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

for `fork` and additionally `#include <errno.h>` for my `errno` addition.