# How can I use wait() as a non-blocking command in Unix?

Tags: c, unix, wait, manpage

From the [wait() man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)

> The wait() system call suspends execution of the calling thread until
>   one of its children terminates.

Regarding why to use wait(), it says

> In the case of a terminated child, performing a wait allows the system
>   to release the resources associated with the child; if a wait is not
>   performed, then the terminated child remains in a "zombie" state

So, it is a good practice to use wait() & wait() is blocking command. That is what I derive from the man page.

How to use wait() but in a non-blocking way so that the calling thread can go about its business & when child state changes, it gets notified.

Comment: From wait man page "WNOHANG     return immediately if no child has exited." (use `waitpid()`,  `wait()` is obsolete)

Comment: @Stargateur if I use **wait()** it will always be blocking but if I use **waitpid()** I have the option of making it non-blocking right?

Comment: *"when child state changes, it gets notified"* – That's what `SIGCHLD` is for.

Comment: @MartinR so, you are saying I should use **SIGCHLD** to ignore all children so that I don't have to **wait()**. If my parent has a loop of instructions it's supposed to perform, then call **wait()** at the end to see if any child is dead & if yes than release resource of that child. Is that correct?

Comment: What I (roughly) mean is that you register a signal handler for SIGCHLD, and set a flag if it is called. In your main event loop check if the flag is set – then you can safely call wait().

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171722/how-can-i-handle-sigchld-in-c.

Answer (score 2):

`wait()` is always blocking.
`waitpid()` can be used for blocking or non-blocking.

we can use `waitpid()` as a non-blocking system call with the following format:

`int pid = waitpid(child_pid, &status, WNOHANG);`

`WNOHANG`-->Returns immediately regardless of the child’s status.

Reference:https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kauffman/4061/04-making-processes.pdf
Page no:13 (Non-Blocking waitpid()).

Comment: If there is anything wrong with my answer, please tell me.