# My code doesn't seem to run before it ends

Tags: c, linux, memory, exit

I have created an application that uses shared memory and child processes. When I want the program to close, I use my function 'controlledEnd' to kill any remaining child processes and destroy the shared memory but it seems that the code in the function does not get ran/does not complete and the print statements are never printed.

```
 /*
  controlledEnd

  This function safely exits the program ensuring there are no
  memory leaks and that the memory segment is freed.   

  The function takes 1 parameter
    -pid_t segmentID
        The segmentID of the shared memory
*/
void controlledEnd(pid_t segmentID){

    /*Kills all child processes*/
    if((int)kill(0, SIGKILL)==0){
        printf("All jobs successfully killed");
    }

    /*Logs an error if processes were not successfully killed*/
    else{
        logError("Any", "Could not kill processes on exit");
        perror("Could not deallocate memory on exit");
    }

    /*Frees the segment of shared memory used for the queue*/
    if((int)shmctl(segmentID, IPC_RMID, 0)==0){
        printf("Memory successfully deallocated");
    }

    /*Logs an error if the memory was not deallocated successfully*/
    else{
        logError("Either", "Could not deallocate memory on exit");
        perror("Could not deallocate memory on exit");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(0);
}
```

Any idea as to why my shared memory segment isn't being destroyed properly?

Comment: Have you looked at what `kill(0, SIGKILL)` actually *does*?

Comment: I assume with 0 being passed as it's first parameter, SIGKILL is sent to every process in the process group

Comment: I've added an answer that spells it out but if you'd have thought about what EOF said you wouldn't have needed it. :-)

Comment: Crucially, you can't even catch the `SIGKILL` in the `kill()`ing process.

Comment: You might also need to worry about zombies, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171722/how-can-i-handle-sigchld/7171836#7171836

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of the man page for kill(3)

> If pid is 0, sig shall be sent to all processes (excluding an
>   unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal
>   to the process group ID of the sender, and for which the process has
>   permission to send a signal.

So the process calling kill is part of the process group so it's killed along with all of the children and none of your tidyup code runs after that.

Comment: I should have realised this much earlier. Thanks!