# Get status of execl from a process that does not exit

Tags: c, process, exec, fork, job-scheduling

I need to find a way to get status from an execl command. I call execl for a process that needs to run as daemon (background process), that will be inherited by init process. However, the process that I try to execl may exit even though the execl call itself did not fail. So, execl runs succesfully and does not returns to parent code, but the process that I try to execl may exit abnormally. I fork two times from the main process, run execl in grandchild process, exit child process based on the status of the grandchild which will be captured by the main process and success or failure will be returned to the caller.

The problem with is that in the child process (parent of the execl'ed process)  I cannot use waitpid without WNOHANG, otherwise if execl'ed process does not exit, it would wait forever, on the other hand I cannot use with WNOHANG because then if the child process is scheduled before grandchild (that calls execl), it would just say grandchild is not exitted (which is the success case in my application), even though the grandchild may exit abnormally after execl is executed.

I tried to use a pipe but I think it didn't work. (a context switch after pipe write, and before execl or a multicore scheduling would ruin everything again) I am attaching the code segment here, that is similar to what I try to use. Could please you help me to solve the problem here? Thanks.

```
 int pid;
    pid = fork();
    const char* command_cstr = "pwd";  // this is only a placeholder.
    if ( pid < 0 ) {
            return -1;
    }
    if ( pid == 0 ) {  // CHILD CODE
            int fd[2];
            int val;
            setsid();  
            pipe(fd);
            pid = fork();
            if ( pid < 0 ) {
                    exit(1);
            }
            if ( pid == 0 ) {  // GRANDCHILD CODE
                    close(fd[0]);
                    val = 1;
                    write(fd[1], &val, sizeof(val));
                    close(fd[1]);
                    execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", command_cstr, NULL);
                    exit(1);  // exits only when execl returns on error
            }
            // CHILD CODE
            // wait until grandchild process is executed
            close(fd[1]);
            read(fd[0], &val, sizeof(val));  // blocks until child writes
            close(fd[0]);
            int grandchild_status;
            waitpid(pid, &grandchild_status, WNOHANG);
            if (WIFEXITED(grandchild_status) == false) {
                    exit(0); // success case, execl alive
            } else {
                    exit(1);  // fail case, execl exitted
            }
    }
    // PARENT CODE
    // Reap the child, leaving the grandchild to be inherited by init
    int child_status;
    waitpid(pid, &child_status, 0);
    // If the child exited with 0, it managed to fork and execl didn't exit
    if (WIFEXITED(child_status) && WEXITSTATUS(child_status) == 0) {
            // Child forked and exited successfully
            return 0;
    } else {
            // If the child did not exit with 0 
            return -1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can handle the SIGCHLD signal. See for example: [Example of waitpid, WNOHANG, and SIGCHLD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155810/example-of-waitpid-wnohang-and-sigchld)

Comment: Sounds like XY-problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I work on a project that runs as an agent on a Linux machine that will handle the tasks come from a remote center. One of the tasks is starting or stopping Suricata (an IDS/IPS system). Agent can receive the start command, thus needs to start Suricata independently from the Agent process itself. I try to start Suricata with an exec call. (from a script or directly) The exec command itself may fail and return, or if it does not fail the Suricata process may fail after calling exec. (i.e the wrong config etc.) The success case is that Suricata runs as an independent process. (child of init)